# Passing shipping address from paypal button to php script

Tags: php, paypal

Ok, so assume a php script called checkout contains the following parameters:
address
productid

Now there is a paypal buy now button on the website, now I can use the php script to pass a product id since there is an option to direct users to a certain page upon purchase, but how would one pass the shipping address through too?

Comment: How are you passing the `productid` to the next page? Assuming it's passed as a GET or POST variable, can't you just pass the address in the same way?

Comment: @aerotwelve if the directed url is website/checkout.php?productid=123&address={insert address to ship to}

Comment: Can you be more specific why passing the user's shipping address as a GET variable (as you referenced in your previous comment) doesn't work in your example?